gnuplot 6.0 zsort doubles first column, unlike gnuplot 5.4
I'm trying to sort just the 1st column of the following file ("dat0.txt"):
 1.4     46  0.2
 1.9     49  0.2
 1.9     53  0.3
 1.9     53  0.3
 2.5     53  0.2
 1.9     54  0.2
 1.8     56  0.3
 0.6     55  0.3
 0.8     54  0.1
 1.1     54  0.3
 1.2     56  0
 1.6     71  0
 1.2     75  0.3
 0.7     76  0.4
 1.1     76  0.3
 1.3     75  0.3
 0.4     73  0.4
 1.7     75  0.4
 0.6     77  0.5
 0.2     75  0.5
 0.7     76  0.4
 0.6     76  0.4
 0.5     76  0.6
 1   76  0.5
 0.7     77  0.5
 1.7     78  0.3
 1.8     78  0.3
 1.1     76  0.4
 1.7     76  0.3
 1.8     77  0.4
 2   77  0.2
 1.8     79  0.3
 1.7     80  0.1
 1.6     81  0.1
 1.5     82  0.2
 1.9     82  0.3
 1.5     82  0.2
 1.5     82  0.2
 1.6     82  0.1
 1.6     83  0.1
 1.7     84  0.3
 1.6     84  0.3
 1.9     84  0.3
 0.5     84  0.3
 1.8     84  0.2
 1.5     84  0.2
 1.3     82  0.3
 2.5     79  0.1
 1.8     77  0.1
 2.3     76  0.1
 2.5     74  0.1
 0.7     73  0
 0.8     73  -0.1
 1.5     76  0.1
 1.4     78  0
 1.9     79  0.1
 0.9     79  0
 0.9     80  0.2
 1.7     78  0.1
 2.4     73  0.1
 2.6     70  0.1
 3.1     69  0.2
 3.2     67  0.4
 2.2     64  0.2
 2.3     64  0.5
 2.9     61  0.5
 2.2     61  0.1
 2.1     66  0.4
 2   68  0.2
 1.8     67  0.6
 3.9     65  0
 3.5     65  1.1
 4.2     56  0.8
 3.8     60  0.2
 2.6     65  0.8
 6.6     70  -0.5
 2   73  0.5
 0.4     71  0.3
 1.4     66  0.7
 0.9     60  1.2
 2   60  1
 2.1     61  0.6
 0.8     63  0.5
 0.6     67  0.3
 0.6     68  0.4
 1.4     71  0.2
 2.5     68  -0.1
 2.3     70  0.2
 1.1     73  0.1
 0.7     77  0.3
 0.8     78  0.3
 0.3     78  0.2
 1.2     79  0.1
 2.1     82  0.1
 0.8     82  0.2
 0   79  0.3
 0.1     78  0.2
 0.6     79  0.2
 0   80  0.2
 1   81  0.2
 1.4     81  0.4
 0.8     81  0.3
 1.4     81  0.3
 1.1     81  0.2
 0   81  0.3
 0.7     81  0.2
 0.9     80  0.1
 0.6     80  0.4
 0.3     76  0.6
 0.2     73  0.4
 0.4     74  0.6
 0.1     75  0.8
 0.1     74  0.7
 0.9     70  0.7
 1.7     66  1
 1.5     60  1.3
 1.6     57  1.4
 0.5     54  1.1
 0.9     50  0.8
 0.8     46  1
 1.5     45  0.9
 2.1     45  1
 2.6     43  0.9
 4.3     43  1.1
 4.6     44  1
 4.7     44  0.7
 5.5     44  0.9
 4.3     45  1.1
 4.7     46  0.9
 4.1     46  0.9
 4.1     48  0.8
 4.7     52  0.7
 3.9     53  0.6
 3.8     54  0.3
 3   54  0.4
 3.2     57  0.3
 2.8     61  0.4
 1.7     62  0.3
 1.8     63  0.3
 0.9     65  0.3
 1.3     68  0.3
 1.8     69  0.3
 1   69  0.4
 0.8     68  0.3
 0.7     68  0.2
 0.5     69  0.2
 0.1     70  0.3
 0   70  0.3
 0   69  0.3
 1.5     71  0.1
 0.7     72  0.1
 0.8     74  0.3
 0.9     74  0.2
 0.3     75  0.1
 0   74  0.1
 0   74  0.1
 0.1     75  0.3
 0.3     74  0.4
 0   72  0.7
 0   66  0.2
 0.1     61  -0.1
 0.3     59  0.5
 0.9     56  0.5
 1.6     55  0.9

If I run the following script
reset session
FILE = "dat0.txt"
    set xrange [*:*]
    set yrange [*:*]
    set format x
    set format y ""
    set table $Data0
    plot FILE  u 1:2:1 smooth zsort
    unset table

with gnuplot 5.4 for windows, everything goes well: I've got the 1st column well sorted, followed by the R character i. With version 6.0 instead, the first columns gets doubled:
 0  0  i
 0  0  i
 0  0  i
 0  0  i
 0  0  i
 0  0  i
 0  0  i
 0  0  i
 0  0  i
 0.1  0.1  i
 0.1  0.1  i
 0.1  0.1  i
 0.1  0.1  i
 0.1  0.1  i
 0.1  0.1  i
 0.2  0.2  i
 0.2  0.2  i
 0.3  0.3  i
 0.3  0.3  i
 0.3  0.3  i
 0.3  0.3  i
 0.3  0.3  i
 0.4  0.4  i
 0.4  0.4  i
 0.4  0.4  i
 0.5  0.5  i
 0.5  0.5  i
 0.5  0.5  i
 0.5  0.5  i
 0.6  0.6  i
 0.6  0.6  i
 0.6  0.6  i
 0.6  0.6  i
 0.6  0.6  i
 0.6  0.6  i
 0.6  0.6  i
 0.7  0.7  i
 0.7  0.7  i
 0.7  0.7  i
 0.7  0.7  i
 0.7  0.7  i
 0.7  0.7  i
 0.7  0.7  i
 0.7  0.7  i
 0.8  0.8  i
 0.8  0.8  i
 0.8  0.8  i
 0.8  0.8  i
 0.8  0.8  i
 0.8  0.8  i
 0.8  0.8  i
 0.8  0.8  i
 0.8  0.8  i
 0.9  0.9  i
 0.9  0.9  i
 0.9  0.9  i
 0.9  0.9  i
 0.9  0.9  i
 0.9  0.9  i
 0.9  0.9  i
 0.9  0.9  i
 0.9  0.9  i
 1  1  i
 1  1  i
 1  1  i
 1.1  1.1  i
 1.1  1.1  i
 1.1  1.1  i
 1.1  1.1  i
 1.1  1.1  i
 1.2  1.2  i
 1.2  1.2  i
 1.2  1.2  i
 1.3  1.3  i
 1.3  1.3  i
 1.3  1.3  i
 1.4  1.4  i
 1.4  1.4  i
 1.4  1.4  i
 1.4  1.4  i
 1.4  1.4  i
 1.4  1.4  i
 1.5  1.5  i
 1.5  1.5  i
 1.5  1.5  i
 1.5  1.5  i
 1.5  1.5  i
 1.5  1.5  i
 1.5  1.5  i
 1.5  1.5  i
 1.6  1.6  i
 1.6  1.6  i
 1.6  1.6  i
 1.6  1.6  i
 1.6  1.6  i
 1.6  1.6  i
 1.6  1.6  i
 1.7  1.7  i
 1.7  1.7  i
 1.7  1.7  i
 1.7  1.7  i
 1.7  1.7  i
 1.7  1.7  i
 1.7  1.7  i
 1.7  1.7  i
 1.8  1.8  i
 1.8  1.8  i
 1.8  1.8  i
 1.8  1.8  i
 1.8  1.8  i
 1.8  1.8  i
 1.8  1.8  i
 1.8  1.8  i
 1.8  1.8  i
 1.9  1.9  i
 1.9  1.9  i
 1.9  1.9  i
 1.9  1.9  i
 1.9  1.9  i
 1.9  1.9  i
 1.9  1.9  i
 2  2  i
 2  2  i
 2  2  i
 2  2  i
 2.1  2.1  i
 2.1  2.1  i
 2.1  2.1  i
 2.1  2.1  i
 2.2  2.2  i
 2.2  2.2  i
 2.3  2.3  i
 2.3  2.3  i
 2.3  2.3  i
 2.4  2.4  i
 2.5  2.5  i
 2.5  2.5  i
 2.5  2.5  i
 2.5  2.5  i
 2.6  2.6  i
 2.6  2.6  i
 2.6  2.6  i
 2.8  2.8  i
 2.9  2.9  i
 3  3  i
 3.1  3.1  i
 3.2  3.2  i
 3.2  3.2  i
 3.5  3.5  i
 3.8  3.8  i
 3.8  3.8  i
 3.9  3.9  i
 3.9  3.9  i
 4.1  4.1  i
 4.1  4.1  i
 4.2  4.2  i
 4.3  4.3  i
 4.3  4.3  i
 4.6  4.6  i
 4.7  4.7  i
 4.7  4.7  i
 4.7  4.7  i
 5.5  5.5  i
 6.6  6.6  i

Is that a bug or am I doing anything wrong ?

Simple answer, but without explanation why it is like this and why there is a difference between 5.4 and 6.0.
Simply remove the line
set format y ""

and it should work similarly in 6.0 like in 5.4. Actually, with 2 columns in 5.4 and 3 columns in 6.0.

Version 6 is doing exactly what you asked: it is printing the y value with format "", i.e. it prints nothing at all for y. I do not know why version 5.4 was doing something else.  If you change that to something like set format y "%6.3f" you will see how that works.
As @theozh mentioned, version 5 normally prints only x and y in tabular output.  Version 6 also prints z if it seems relevant. I will mention that there is a another documented difference between zsort in version 5 and version 6, although I think it isn't relevant to this particular case.
Gnuplot 5 offered several data pre-processing operations selected by the keyword smooth.  smooth zsort was one of these.
Gnuplot 6 distinguishes between "filter" operations and "smoothing" operations.

gnuplot> help filter
Filter operations are applied immediately after
reading input data, before  applying any smoothing or style-specific
processing options.  In general the purpose of a filter is to replace
the original full set of   input points with a selected subset of
points, possibly modified, regrouped,  or reordered,  The filters
currently supported are bins, convexhull, concavehull,  mask,
sharpen, and zsort.

So in version 6 the recommended way to do what you want would be
plot 'dat0.txt' using 1:2:1 zsort

Note that zsort in this command does not request a smoothing operation, only the zsort filter.  In principle you could add a smoothing operation also to get something like plot DATA using 1:2:3 zsort smooth csplines, which would first sort the points on z and then fit splines to the re-ordered [x,y] pairs.
For backwards compatibility version 6 also accepts zsort as a smoothing option. Hypothetically you could request both a filter (other than zsort) that would be applied first and the followed by the sort operation on z applied to the filtered data. I can't at the moment think of a sensible example.

@ifffam your plot command is u 1:2:1, so in gnuplot 6.0  you get x,y,x. If you set format y '', you will get x,x. My guess would have been that if you set format z '' you might get x,y and suppress the 3rd column, but apparently it's not the case. However, if you set format x '' you will get y,x if you only want two columns.
